# i install Magik_Featuredproducts component in magento after install i can't access my front view?

Tags: magento

i install Magik_Featuredproducts component via magento connect after install component i can access backend but cant access frontend and following error comes:-
Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on line 529.
how to solve this error?...hope someone help me.

Comment: try to install XDebug, so that you get a stack trace and not just an error on one line.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like one of the php files under the module Block folder is missing.  `toHtml()` is called on a Block.  Check that you've set the permissions on the module to be `755` and that all files are present.